# Грузовик чи вантажівка?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Вчергове вивчаючи особливості української мови, зокрема на ресурсі "Мова – ДНК нації" [наткнувся](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/nagolos/nagolos-u-slovi-vantazhivka) на досить цікавий факт: дискусія щодо правильного написання/існування слів "вантажівка" і "грузовик", зокрема там наголошено:

> Крім того, пам'ятайте, що правильно говорити: вантаж, вантажний, вантажити, завантажувати, навантаження. А от «груз», «грузовий», «грузити», «загружати», «загрузка», «грузовик» – це суржикові форми.

А от користувачі, в коментарях, наводять, що в СУМ ці слова існують одночасно:
І дійсно - СУМ-11 [наводить](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghruzovyk):

> **ГРУЗОВИК**, а, чол., розм. Вантажний автомобіль. *Грузовик повернув із широкої вулиці в цей заулок і одразу застряв (Юрій Яновський, I, 1958, 197).*

а слово "вантажівка" [з'являється](http://sum.in.ua/f/vantazhivka) тільки у "Вільному тлумачному словнику української мови / Новітньому онлайновому словнику української мови (2013—2018)":

> **Вантажі́вка**, -и, жін.
>   Вантажний автомобіль; ваговоз.
>   *Аж ось почувся гуркіт моторів — «їдуть!» — і до Народного дому підкотила чорна легкова машина, а за нею.. причмихала вантажівка    (Василь Шкляр, Залишенець, 2010);
>   На площі стояло чотири вантажівки кольору хакі, набиті солдафонами в брудно-зеленій уніформі    (Максим Кідрук, Мексиканські хроніки, 2009);
>   Потім я падав під вантажівку з п'ятьма тонами мокрої дощової капусти    (Юрій Андрухович, Таємниця, 2007).*

Офіційний сайт Української мови [наполягає](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/antisurzhik_pravilna_mova/5-1-0-244), що "грузовик" - це суржик:

> *грузовик – вантажна машина, вантажівка*

ЗМІ здебільшого використовують слово "*вантажівка*":

> Електрична вантажівка від Tesla буде безпілотною - Ілон Маск | [Економічна правда](https://www.epravda.com.ua/news/2017/11/17/631271/).

Отже "*грузовик*" - невірне вживання?
І єдиним та правильним буде - "вантажівка" або "вантажний автомобіль"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Словник-антисуржик](http://slovopedia.org.ua/45/53395/299771.html)

> ГРУЗОВИК  вантажна машина, вантажівка

Хоч слово ***"грузовик"*** присутнє в словниках СУМ-11 та СУМ-20, але біля нього є позначка *розмовне*.

Тобто вживати можна слово ***"грузовик"***, не можемо вживати в діломому письмі та офіційних документах.

Варто надавати перевагу вживанню слова ***"вантажівка".***

[Словник синонімів:](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B6%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

ВАНТА́ЖІ́ВКА (вантажний автомобіль), ВАГОВО́З, ВАНТА́ЖКА *розм.*,ВАНТА́ЖНА *розм.*